# discrete logarithm problem of ecc

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

I have read a lot about the *discrete logarithm problem of ecc*, but I still do not understand the problem as follows:

We have ***domain parameters: (p, E, P, n, h),*** where ***n*** is the ***order group of P***.

The process of creating privatekey - publickey is as follows:

1. Select a random number ***k under [1, n - 1]***
2. Calculate ***Q = kP***
3. Return ***Q*** is *publickey*, ***k*** is *privatekey*.

*As far as I know, domain paramters and Q will be public. But, suppose I was the eavesdropper, I know P produces 1000 points (as the parameter n), because Q = kP so Q will be a point in point set generated by P, so I can generate order group P and see the position of Q for privatekey k (since k is in [1, n-1]).*

***For example***: P generate 0P, P, 2P, 3P, ... 1000P. I choose k under [1,999] is 120 -> Q = 120P -> position of Q in the order group P is 120 -> k = 120.

***So if I know P and Q, then I know privatekey then ??? So where is it safe?***

I suppose so because NIST gives you some recommended domain parameters and I think the order group has to be pre-calculated to save on computational cost.

Thank you for everyone's help!

Comment: Consider that in a practical parametrization, $n$ and $k$ have at least 48 decimal digits, rather than 3 in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The poblem of computing the private key $d$ from the public key $Q$ is indeed referred to as $ECDLP$. It is crucial that you choose the domain parameters so that the $ECDLP$ is intractable. Concerning your choice of $d$ ... it is too small and can thus be computed efficiently. Imagine $d$ not having 7 Bits like in your example but 192-, 384- or even 512 Bits. You wouldn't get very far using your method (or any other currently known and implementable algorithm).

In order for the $ECDLP$ to be intractable, $d$ must be adequately chosen so that you cannot just brute-force all values for $d$ until you find a $d$ so that $dP = Q$. This is why curves that are considered as secure today use large values for $n$ and $p$ and create a random value $d$ in the range $[1\dots n-1]$.

Comment: Correction: crypto libraries do not set the msbit of $d$ in order to make brute-force search (or even a square-root time search) harder; it's easy to show it doesn't.  Now, there are libraries that do set the msbit, but those libraries do it for subtler reasons (dealing with potential side channel attacks)

Comment: Oh good to know! I edited the msb part!